# C# Show IEnumerable elements

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result = GetCombinations(Enumerable.Range(1, 3), 2);

        }

        static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
        {
            if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });

            return GetCombinations(list, length - 1)
                .SelectMany(t => list, (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
        }
```

Question is, How I can show all elements from `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result`

Comment: what do you mean by "show"?

Comment: Soemthing like Console.WriteLine(result[n]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> resultList= GetCombinations(Enumerable.Range(1, 3), 2);
foreach (var result in resultList)
 {
    foreach(var element in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }       
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use SelectMany to flatten the result.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result = GetCombinations(Enumerable.Range(1, 3), 2);
foreach (var combination in resultList.SelectMany(x => x))
    Console.WriteLine(combination);
```

If you intend to itterate multiple times you should also add .ToLost() to improve performance.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result = GetCombinations(Enumerable.Range(1, 3), 2).ToList();
```

Comment: I feel like `(x => x)` is becoming a thing after comments that it looks like emoticon :]